# Glitch in Call of Duty World at War?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war

For some reason, when I'm playing *Call of Duty: World at War* my character's arm will revert itself while holding a python. (It looks like it is shooting me).

How can I fix that, so I can record videos properly?

Comment: Really needs screenshots or video.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't *find* anything, but this could be, if using PC, a damaged installation.
Try re-installing it if you are on PC. You can also do this on console.
It may also be damaged disc?